# Unable to read memory address of variable that pass to function as call by reference

Tags: delphi

I am Delphi 6 developer. And trying to call C++ dll function from delphi.
Dll written in C++ and the have Char pointer as out parameter.

Eg.

```
Function doGetStatus(Var szStatusData : Char) : Integer; cdecl; external 'WhizCal.dll';
```

When I call function from DLL I send char variable 'szStatusData'  and return value should be 'Down' or 'Live' but it retuens only 'D' or 'L' this is because I have passed Char variable reference.
My question is, what can I do for getting return data as 'Down' or 'Live'  without changing datatype.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is just a single character. So you cannot expect more.

Most likely the C++ code expects to be passed a pointer to an array of characters. Perhaps it should be like this:

```
function doGetStatus(szStatusData: PAnsiChar): Integer; cdecl; external 'WhizCal.dll';
```

And you might call it like this:

```
var
  StatusData: array [0..255] of AnsiChar;
  RetVal: Integer;
....
RetVal := doGetStatus(StatusData);
// check RetVal
```

We cannot tell you what exactly your code should be because we don't have any details of the specified interface. Unless the caller also passes the length of the array, such a function is bait for buffer overrun errors. As written above, this is the case. How can the caller know how much space to allocate. Well designed functions also allow the caller to pass the length of the array that they supplied.

My general advice to you is that interop is a topic that demands precision and detail, and knowledge of both sides of the boundary. You need to find out that detail.

Comment: Thank you for suggesssion. Now its work fine for some functions.

Comment: So, is this the answer?

Comment: Not exactly, but its work for function having only one out parameter. I have to call other c functions that require in and out parameter. But when I call that function with changes suggested by you ..it shows access violation at the end of function call. Its pleasure to have your suggessions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: We did this last time. It's no fun. You ask more and more questions in comments and ignore the original question. No thanks.